# .get() returning letters rather than strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that is structured as such:

```
json_data = [{'a':10,'text':"Salam"},{'a':4,'text':"Hello Friend"}]
```

I have been able to iterate through the list and extract the key 'text' from each dictionary:

```
json1_text = [[[value] for value in json1_data[index].get('text')] for
              index in range(len(json1_data))]
```

However, the new json1_text list does not contain sentences from returned from the dictionary, but rather each individual letter:

```
json1_text[0]
```

Returns:

```
[['S'],['a'],['l'],['a'],['m']]
```

How would I be able to return the whole sentence "Hello Friend" as opposed to each individual letter and storing each in a list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I lost you at `key 'text' from each dictionary`. Your dictionaries in `json_data` don't have the key `'text'`.

Comment: +jpp, the dictionary is structured like such NOT exactly the same - it's actually an extremely complex dictionary. My problem is not related to a keyerror, so what the key is or isn't has no impact on the issue. @Henry Yik was able to provide me the correct syntax for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json1_text = [v for i in json_data for k,v in i.items() if isinstance(v,str)]
print (json1_text)
```

Result:

```
['Salam', 'Hello Friend']
```